# Groupby and count on lines of a text file in Windows CMD

Tags: sorting, cmd, grouping

I have a long files with identifiers, e.g.

```
A
A
B
C
A
C
```

I would like to do a group by, count and sort operation to get a file with:

```
A 3
C 2
B 1
```

How can I achieve it in a CMD script?

Comment: Your output is not sorted ;-)

Comment: @dbenham, it is sorted by frequency. However, sorting by name is potentially useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Global edit*** - *All code has been modified to allow `-` in identifiers. Identifiers must not contain `!`*

Assuming the identifiers do not contain `=` or `$` or `!`, and the identifiers are NOT case sensitive, the following lists the counts sorted by identifier.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Clear any existing $ variables
for /f "delims==" %%V in ('set $ 2^>nul') do set "%%V="

:: Get a count of each identifier
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("test.txt") do (
  set /a "cnt=!$%%A!+1"
  set "$%%A=!cnt!"
)

:: Write the results to a new file
>output.txt (
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=$=" %%A in ('set $') do echo %%A %%B
)

:: Show the result
type output.txt
```

The prefix can be adapted as needed. But this technique cannot be used if the identifiers are case sensitive.

**EDIT**

Here is a version that sorts the result by count descending

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Clear any existing $ variables
for /f "delims==" %%V in ('set $ 2^>nul') do set "%%V="

:: Get a count of each identifier
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("test.txt") do (
  set /a "cnt=!$%%A!+1"
  set "$%%A=!cnt!"
)

:: Write a temp file with zero padded counts prefixed to the left.
>temp.txt (
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=$=" %%A in ('set $') do (
    set "cnt=000000000000%%B"
    echo !cnt:~-12!=%%A=%%B
  )
)

:: Sort and write the results to a new file
>output.txt (
  for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=$=" %%A in ('sort /r temp.txt') do echo %%A %%B
)
del "temp.txt"

:: Show the result
type output.txt
```

---

**EDIT 2**

And here is another option sorted by count descending that assumes [REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) is somewhere within your PATH

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Clear any existing $ variables
for /f "delims==" %%V in ('set $ 2^>nul') do set "%%V="

:: Get a count of each identifier
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("test.txt") do (
  set /a "cnt=!$%%A!+1"
  set "$%%A=!cnt!"
)

:: Sort result by count descending and write to output file
set $|repl "\$(.*)=(.*)" "000000000000$2=$1 $2"|repl ".*(.{12}=.*)" $1|sort /r|repl ".{13}(.*)" $1 >output.txt

:: Show the result
type output.txt
```

Comment: The sort order appears to be by frequency.

Comment: @Magoo - Oooh, I missed that interpretation. You are probably correct.

Comment: @Magoo - sort order fixed :)

Comment: Looks really good! The only issue I have is that some of these names seem to have a `-` sign in them, and so I get `Missing operator.` error.

Comment: @Grzenio - I modified all code to allow `-` in identifiers.